# wordpress check wp_head and wp_footer

Tags: plugins

I am creating a plugin to add some javascript to Wordpress's theme header and footer.

I'm doing this through the following wordpress hooks:

```
add action(wp_head,function_name)
add action(wp_footer,function_name)
```

However my plugin can't add script if the clients theme does not have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` functions.

Is there any possibility that I can use `if-else` in my plugin to check to see if the client's theme has `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` functions.

Or is there any possibilty to add my javascript before `</head>` and `</body>` tag
without using `wp_head` and `wp_footer` hooks.

Answer (score 6):

Technically to check if theme runs `wp_head` and `wp_footer` hooks you can:

1. hook into `shutdown`
2. check that you are in front end
3. use [`did_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/did_action) to determine if hooks fired
4. save the result (in option for example) with theme name to access and use later

However in practice I agree with Chip Bennet that these hooks are essential. Trying to code for case when they are not there is simply not practical (same like trying to code for ancient WP version and such).

Answer (score 4):

To determine the existence of these template tag calls, you'd have to read the contents of the current Theme's `header.php` and `footer.php` template files (and probably `index.php`, too, just for good measure, to cover the oddball Themes), and look for the template tag call string.

But that really doesn't get you anywhere, because without the existence of those template tags, you have no way of injecting content into the document head or footer.

Any Theme that doesn't call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` has far bigger problems, though; they are essential to core functionality at this point.

Comment: +1 on 'Any Theme that doesn't call wp_head() and wp_footer() has far bigger problems'

Answer (score -1):

Check this code: https://gist.github.com/378450

Is a complete solution to check usage both of this function. Code prints string, using `wp_head` and `wp_footer` actions, then make a self request to obtain code and check this strings. If doesn't exist add report page.

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: Ok, I have added explanation.

Answer (score -5):

Why not try using:

> if(function_exists('wp_head')) {
>     //do something
>     }else{
>     //something else
>     }

Comment: Ok you mean i can use this if(function_exist(wp_head)) in my Plugin. its an good idea but if wp_head function not exist how i can add my javasript in theme's header and footer.

Comment: That will only return true if the user has a WordPress version older than 1.5 (for `wp_footer()`) or 1.2 (for `wp_head()`), as those were the versions in which the two functions were added to WordPress.

Comment: wp_head() always exist (depent on wp version).

Comment: Now a days it returns true :)